# PHP - Setting div points on circumference of circle

Tags: php, math, geometry

Here's the rundown... I've got a circle, I've got some divs I want to "bend" around it. Just like a circle table with various numbers of chairs around it.

I've ran a few stuff down, my brains not hitting at this hour, would really love to knock it out so I can sleep.  Anyone?

```
                <?
                    $r=45; //px     
                    for($x=0; $x<$gu; $x++){
                        $deg = 360/$gu*$x;
                        $rad = deg2rad($deg);
                        $xx = (cos($rad) * $r);
                        $yy = (sin($rad) * $r);
                        ?>
                            <b style="left:<?=round($r+$xx)?>px; top:<?=round($r+$yy)?>px"></b>
                        <?
                    }
                ?>
```

Comment: u need to set something like 360/n and place it according to the calculation.

Comment: can you share your code so far?

Comment: would love to share the code, but i've changed it so many times that it's not useful lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- sin(angle) × radius will get you the Y-coordinate of the item, and cos(angle) × radius will get you the X-coordinate of the item, both relative to the centre of the circle.
- You can get the angle by dividing 360° by the number of `<div>`s.
- You can convert degrees to radians by multiplying by π/180.

Comment: I've got that, but what about the part for each div now.  x1= cos($deg) * $rad; x2= cos($deg) * $rad? = where would I input div#2, div#3? i'm probably missing something really stupid, it's just not clicking.

Comment: @MichaelMikhjian: You'll want a loop. There's a separate set of coordinates for each one...

Comment: for($x=0; $x<$gu; $x++){
       $deg = (360/$gu);
       $xx = cos($deg) * $rad;
       $yy = sin($deg) * $rad;
} //gu = represents total divs, but vars don't variate based on $x, I'm missing that part

Comment: @MichaelMikhjian: `$deg = 360 / $gu * $x;`

Comment: my mistake, makes sense.  I get some weird looking circles though.. few min here, i think i've got something (cause I don't want to use the full 360, i'd rather have 3 or 5 "chairs" closer together on one end of the cirlce, but still following the bend)

Comment: i've added the correct code this answer above, thanks for the assistance!